# Sound Juicer has no menus

Tags: sound-juicer

I installed Sound Juicer via the Ubuntu Software function. Running 18.04.
Default save format is OGG, but I prefer FLAC. Can't change preferences because I have no menus. [screenshot of Sound Juicer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLSCH.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting Sound Juicer prferences](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217102/setting-sound-juicer-prferences)

Answer (score 0):

Found it! Menu items are located under Sound Juicer in the top bar next to Activities.

Comment: I have menu items there, but no preferences :(